# Can't seem to get around java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I am rather new in Java and I can't seem to get around the error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:371)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:384)
    at djurfarm.Animals.huntCatMouse(Animals.java:213)
    at djurfarm.Djurfarm.main(Djurfarm.java:24)
Java Result: 1
```

I know what it means, that the index somewhere is below or above what it should be, but I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening. Maybe it's because I've stared myself blind and won't see where the logic fails. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code for the method:

```
public void huntCatMouse() {
    while (!CatList.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < CatList.size(); i++) {
            try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
                int slump = MouseList.size() - 1;
                int num = CatList.size() - 1;
                Cat CatRemover = CatList.get(num);
                Mouse aMouse = MouseList.get(slump);
                if (aMouse.getStrength().equals(false)) {
                    System.out.println("En katt fångar en mus.");
                    CatList.remove(CatRemover);
                    MouseList.remove(aMouse);
                } else if (aMouse.getStrength().equals(true)) {
                    System.out.println("En mus lyckas fly från en katt.");
                    CatList.remove(CatRemover);
                    MouseList.remove(aMouse);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Fel i CatMouse");
            }
            if (MouseList.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Empty list");
                break;
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're checking the size of MouseList anywhere before calling get on it.

Comment: Have you tried debugging in addition to just inspecting the code?

Comment: What is the value of `MouseList.size()`?

Comment: don't use "for" loops when your condition parameter is changing. That cause problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int slump = MouseList.size()-1;
```

It seems `MouseList` is a empty list and `size` method return 0 and `slump` become -1 and

```
 MouseList.remove(aMouse); // MouseList.remove(-1)
```

causing `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at -1 index.

you have put condition `!CatList.isEmpty()`, It might be `!CatList.isEmpty() && !MouseList.isEmpty()`

Comment: Thank you! Never actually considered that myself, but when you say it, it's obvious. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The error may be because of this:

```
int slump = MouseList.size()-1;
int num = CatList.size()-1;
Cat CatRemover = CatList.get(num);
Mouse aMouse = MouseList.get(slump);
```

Here you are not checking whether `MouseList` or `CatList` size is greater than 0.

So if `MouseList.size()` returns 0,
so `int slump = MouseList.size()-1;` =  `int slump = -1;`

Now when you do `MouseList.get(slump);` it means you are calling `MouseList.get(-1);`

So it throws that exception.

So first check whether the size of the list is greater than 0 (that is not empty).

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the problem is that `slump` is `-1` when you attempt to `get(slump)`.

The reason it gets into that state is that you are not stopping when the mouse list becomes empty.  In particular, the `if (...) { break; }` at the end only breaks out of the *inner* loop.  So you try the condition for the outer loop, start the inner loop again and ... OOOPs!

The obvious fix would be to test both of the lists sizes in the outer loop's condition.

But a better fix would be to get rid of the inner loop entirely.  You can implement this more simply with just one level of looping.

```
    while (!CatList.isEmpty() && !MouseList.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
            int slump = MouseList.size() - 1;
            int num = CatList.size() - 1;
            Cat CatRemover = CatList.get(num);
            Mouse aMouse = MouseList.get(slump);
            if (aMouse.getStrength().equals(false)) {
                System.out.println("En katt fångar en mus.");
                CatList.remove(CatRemover);
                MouseList.remove(aMouse);
            } else if (aMouse.getStrength().equals(true)) {
                System.out.println("En mus lyckas fly från en katt.");
                CatList.remove(CatRemover);
                MouseList.remove(aMouse);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Fel i CatMouse");
        }
    }
```

---

While I have your attention, you need to fix the names of your local variables.  Java variable names should **always** start with a lowercase letter ... according to the Java style guide.  And try to get the indentation right.  It makes your code **so much easier to read**.

Finally, this is really peculiar: `aMouse.getStrength().equals(true)`.

- I would infer that `getStrength()` returns a `boolean`.
- Assuming that, the simple way to test if it is true is simply `aMouse.getStrength()`.
- But "strength" is not a yes/no concept in English.  It is something that you quantify.
- But if "strength" really is a boolean, then the JavaBeans convention says that the method should be called `isStrength()` not `getStrength()`.

Comment: Thank you. I now realise that it is indeed a better idea to get rid of the inner loop, I'll work that out. Regarding the variable names I will definately keep that in mind as well. Again, thank you!